# Set default group for newly created files/folders in linux?

Tags: linux

When I create a new folder in linux it always 'inherits' the same group. What controls the group ownership of newly created files/folders and how is it reconfigured?

I have been reading about suid and sgid, but I'm not sure this is the way to go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `mkdir` command the ownership is set to the user who creates the folder and the group ownership will be set to the primary group of that user.

You can use the `install` command to create a folder with a different ownership:

```
sudo install -o www-data -g www-data -d test
```

The above command creates the folder `test` and sets ownership and group ownership to `www-data` (for example)

---

Of course you can also use

```
sudo -u www-data mkdir test
```

to create a folder owned by `USER` and group owned by it's primary group. It leads to the same results as the `install` command above.

Comment: How do I set the primary group of a user, so that all folders in the future have a different group?

Comment: @hek2mgl-Well you might need a sudo for performing `usermod -g groupname username`,i.e. `sudo usermod -g groupname username` ! Ain't it?

Comment: @shekharsuman yes, if you aren't root you need to become root or use `sudo`.

Answer (score 12):

A better approach is to change the group of the directory so that all new files there are created with a particular group:

```
sudo chgrp www-data /my/dir
sudo chmod g+s /my/dir
```